middleware.js Doesn’t Fire in Subsequent Route with Next/Link
I've encountered an issue with next/Link while using middleware.js for authenticate and authorization .The problem arises When I click on header links ,which trigger a request to the server to retrieve the user's profile .Initially the middleware checks if the user exists ;if not ,it redirects the user to /auth. After authenticating in the app ,I click on the /profile link in header ,but it doesn't work for the subsequence requests using <Link href="/profile"> profile </Link>
and still in /auth route .however if I use <a href="/profile"> profile </a> ,everything works as expected.
header.js
"use client";

import { useUser } from "@/hooks/useUser";
import Link from "next/link";

function HeaderApp() {
  const { profile, isLoading } = useUser();

  return (
    <header className="border-b">
      <ul className="flex justify-evenly">
        <li className="p-4">
          <Link href="/">home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="p-4">
          <Link href="/profile">profile</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="p-4">
          <Link href="/admin">admin</Link >
        </li>
        <li className="p-4">
          <Link href="/auth">login</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  );
}
export default HeaderApp;

and
middleware.js
import { middlewareAuth } from "./utils/middlewareAuth";

export async function middleware(req) {
  const url = req.url;
  const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  if (pathname.startsWith("/profile")) {
    const user = await middlewareAuth(req);
    if (!user) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", url));
  }
  if (pathname.startsWith("/cart")) {
    const user = await middlewareAuth(req);
    if (!user) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", url));
  }
  if (pathname.startsWith("/admin")) {
    const user = await middlewareAuth(req);
    if (!user) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", url));

    if (user && user.role !== "ADMIN")
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/profile/:path*", "/cart/:path*"],
};

I use nextjs 14.2.3
